# Find the x, y point of a string within a text box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

Is there a way to return a point for a string within a text box?  I found a COM function [GetTextExtentPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144937(VS.85).aspx) that will return the length of a string, but I want to know the point where the string starts.

Comment: That's a native function, not a COM function.  (The two are not the same)

Comment: @lcono123 This is interesting I just want to know why, as well as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`GetPositionFromCharIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getpositionfromcharindex.aspx) method.

Answer (score 2):

First, figure out the index of the first character of the string.

```
int index = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(someString);
```

Then use GetPositionFromCharIndex.

```
Point stringPos = textBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(index);
```

(Code not tested, but something like this should work. Of course you will have to deal with the possibility of duplicate occurrences of your string in the textbox.)

Answer (score 0):

what comes to mi mind is to take a snapshot of both the form and text then do some fancy image comparing to find the starting point.. but for this you need to write/download a library that has theese comparing methods... thus becoming very complicated...

why do you need to do this?

Comment: Well I have my own user control, which I'm extending textbox, and I want to add additional functionality to it.  If I have the point of a string I can add some custom graphics to it.